# How do I hide data/field in a List in J2ME

Tags: list, java-me

I am working on a J2ME app which has dynamically generated Lists. Items on this list may be consequently selected, and the selection processed within the commandAction block.

Is there a way to have the IDs of variables populating the List (from a remote database) included in the List item definition as in:

```
this.append("A", null);
this.append("B", null);
```

or:

```
String[] arrayOfValues = {"A", "B"};
new List("Menu", List.IMPLICIT, arrayOfValues, null);
```

such that when an item is selected, perhaps A, I can also have its database ID for perhaps further processing. Is it possible to hide a field/data? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend `List`

Add an `void append(MyNewClass)` method to your extended List class.

`MyNewClass` contains both the String you will append to the List and your database ID

Keep an additional container in your extended List class and make sure that `List.getSelectedIndex()` allows you to find the correct `MyNewClass` object in the container.